# Compiler error when combining Linq + "RangeVariables" + TPL + DynamicTableEntity

Tags: linq, asynchronous, azure, task-parallel-library, azure-storage

I'm looking at the Microsoft-provided sample ["Process Tasks as they Finish"](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364) and adapting that TPL sample for Azure Storage.

The problem I have is marked below where the variable `domainData` reports the errors in the compiler: `Unknown method Select(?) of TableQuerySegment<DynamicTableEntity>`  (fully qualified namespace removed)

I also get the following error `DynamicTableEntity domainData \n\r Unknown type of variable domainData`

```
      /// if you have the necessary references the following most likely should compile and give you same error

            CloudStorageAccount acct = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;

            CloudTableClient client = acct.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable tableSymmetricKeys = client.GetTableReference("SymmetricKeys5");

            TableContinuationToken token = new TableContinuationToken() { };
            TableRequestOptions opt = new TableRequestOptions() { };
            OperationContext ctx = new OperationContext() { ClientRequestID = "ID" };
            CancellationToken cancelToken = new CancellationToken();

            List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

            var task2 = tableSymmetricKeys.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(cancelToken);
            task2.Wait(cancelToken);


            int depth = 3;
            while (true)
            {
                Task<TableQuerySegment<DynamicTableEntity>> task3 = tableSymmetricKeys.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, token, opt, ctx, cancelToken);

                // Run the method
                task3.Wait();

                 Console.WriteLine("Records retrieved in this attempt = " + task3.Result.Count());// + " | Total records retrieved = " + state.TotalEntitiesRetrieved);



        // HELP! This is where I'm doing something the compiler doesn't like
        //
                IEnumerable<Task<int>> getTrustDataQuery =
                              from domainData in task3.Result select QueryPartnerForData(domainData, "yea, search for this.", client, cancelToken);

                // Prepare for next iteration or quit
                if (token == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    token = task3.Result.ContinuationToken;

                    // todo: persist token  token.WriteXml()
                }
            }




    //....

  private static object QueryPartnerForData(DynamicTableEntity domainData, string p, CloudTableClient client, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing a query. In order to test the code I created the following query:

```
TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity> query = new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>()
    .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "temp"));
```

I also added the method `QueryPartnerForData` which doesn't do anything (simply returns null) and everything works fine. So maybe it's an issue with the `QueryPartnerForData` method? The best way to find the actual error is by setting a breakpoint here and there.

A StackOverflowException often means you are stuck in an endless loop. Run through the breakpoints a few times and see where your code is stuck. Could it be that `QueryPartnerForData` calls the other method and that the other method calls `QueryPartnerForData` again?

Comment: I'll clarify: The code doesn't compile the Linq statement, and the StackOverflow comment was a reference to www.stackoverflow.com (not the exception).

Comment: It appears that I'm having issues with Linq and the RangeVariable: DynamicTableEntity

Comment: Strange, I just deleted the line and retyped it and the error went away.  Control-Z and redo didn't expose any differences.  Funny IDE (or plugin) messing with me.